# Flutter - I am building a flutter app which uses Firestore and saves data for users' favorites. Is there a way to update google sheet from firestore?

Tags: flutter, google-sheets, google-cloud-firestore

My app uses Firestore to save favorites for users and my client needs to have the users' favorites but in a googlesheet for creating reports is there a way to export data or sync from firestore to google sheet?

Comment: This gives some promising results: https://www.google.com/search?q=Is+there+a+way+to+update+google+sheet+from+firestore If you tried those and get stuck, we can probably be of more help here.

Comment: I checked it out before posting my question and I couldn't find a solution